# PHP str_replace exceptions

Tags: php, string, exception, replace

I have some customer data that i convert from CSV to json using a php script.

once converted the data is all jumbled together, like this:

[{"Customer Number":"12345","Customer Name":"customer 1","Address Code":"PRIMARY","Salesperson ID":"aa","Ship to Address 1":"12345","Ship to Address 2":"123, fake street","Ship to Address 3":"","Ship to City":"Toronto","Ship to Province":"ONTARIO","Ship to Postal Code":"A1A 1A1","Country Code":"CA","Ship to Country":"CANADA","Ship to Contact Person":"John Doe","Ship to Phone":"416-555-5555","Ship to Fax":"416-555-5552","Shipping Method":"OUR TRUCK","Bill to Address 1":"12345","Bill to Address 2":"123, fake street","Bill to Address 3":"","Bill to City":"Toronto","Bill to Province":"ONTARIO","Bill to Postal Code":"A1A 1A1","Bill to Phone":"416-555-5555","Tax Schedule ID":"HST ON/S","Location Code":"TOR","Payment Terms ID":"30 DAYS PD CHEQUE","Credit Limit Amount":"2,000.00","Comment1":"30D PDC /10/11-NSF=WR BK ACCT","Comment2":"","Hold":"1","Price List":"EASTGEN"}]

.

I then use some str_replace to organize the output and make the it look nice. here's what i have:

$newArray = str_replace(":",": ",json_encode($newArray));

$newArray = str_replace("[","[\n",$newArray);

$newArray = str_replace("{","{\n",$newArray);

$newArray = str_replace(",",",\n",$newArray);

$newArray = str_replace("},","\n},",$newArray);

$newArray = nl2br($newArray);

.

the problem i'm having is that the output appears like this:

[

{

"Customer Number": "12345",

"Customer Name": "customer 1",

"Address Code": "PRIMARY",

"Salesperson ID": "aa",

"Ship to Address 1": "12345",

"Ship to Address 2": "123,

fake street",

"Ship to Address 3": "",

"Ship to City": "Toronto",

"Ship to Province": "ONTARIO",

"Ship to Postal Code": "A1A 1A1",

"Country Code": "CA",

"Ship to Country": "CANADA",

"Ship to Contact Person": "John Doe",

"Ship to Phone": "416-555-5555",

"Ship to Fax": "416-555-5552",

"Shipping Method": "OUR TRUCK",

"Bill to Address 1": "12345",

"Bill to Address 2": "123,

fake street",

"Bill to Address 3": "",

"Bill to City": "Toronto",

"Bill to Province": "ONTARIO",

"Bill to Postal Code": "A1A 1A1",

"Bill to Phone": "416-555-5555",

"Tax Schedule ID": "HST ON/S",

"Location Code": "TOR",

"Payment Terms ID": "30 DAYS PD CHEQUE",

"Credit Limit Amount": "2,

000.00",

"Comment1": "30D PDC /10/11-NSF=WR BK ACCT",

"Comment2": "",

"Hold": "1",

"Price List": "EASTGEN"}]

Please notice Ship to Address 2 , Bill to Address 2 , and Credit Limit Amount. because of my str_replace it added a line break there. the problem is that the app i use that reads the json needs it on the same line to register properly. is there a way that i can replace the comma's with a line break UNLESS they are part of an address or another variable?

Comment: I think you should use regexp

Comment: @NDLombardi , would that allow me to specify exceptions like if the comma is preceeded by a number (that condition seems like it would work)

Comment: Of course, in case you can try this: [http://regexpal.com/](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you modifying a JSON-encoded string? If you're just trying to make it look "pretty", then you should use `json_encode($str, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` - don't do any other modifications to the string.